# Using geometry nodes with curve modifier causes materials to be stripped

Tags: materials, modifiers, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I'm using geometry nodes to create a procedural road with barriers / signs etc., I then apply a curve modifier for the road to follow a path which works as expected except that it strips the materials from the procedural object.

Is there any workaround for this until the curve deform node is added?

https://developer.blender.org/T88702

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I think you ran into the same issue as https://developer.blender.org/T85962 . It is supposed to be fixed in the next 3.0.0 release

Comment: I've just attached a screenshot with the nodes and the effect after applying the curve modifier. I've just downloaded the 3.0 Alpha and using the material nodes solves this issue. 

However something that works for 2.93 would be great in case I run into any bugs for production

Comment: @Gorgious - ah right, that's good to know so I don't spend time endlessly trying to find a solution! I'll work with 3.0 for now and guess I can always export the geometry back to 2.93 if anything goes wrong. Thanks!